# Plot a column having more than one value per cell

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization

I have a question: Which of the following devices you have used?
Options

```
1. Phone
2. PC
3. Laptop
```

So, some answers are in the form:

```
1,3
2,3
1,2,3
```

I want a Barplot `[Device type in X, count in Y]` where `(1,3)` would contribute to both 1 and 3. How to do that in Plotly/Matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that for each answer you add as many rows as many devices for that user. For example,

```
1,3
2,3
1,2,3
```

would become, using a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Device':['Phone', 'Laptop', 'PC', 'Laptop', 'Phone', 'PC', 'Laptop']})

>>>
   Device
0   Phone
1  Laptop 
2      PC
3  Laptop
4   Phone
5      PC
6  Laptop

sns.countplot(data=df, x='Device')
```

[image]